# How to build a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to build a table dynamicly with reactJS but have two questions that I can´t solve :

1. In the GridList component I got this row `<GridRow data={data1} key={i} />` I dont really want to fetch the "global" var but instead use the data that are sent in to the method? How do I do this?
2. In the GridRow I need too loop the columns(as I do right now) but I need to get the proper cell value and right no I just gets this exception : `Error while rendering "GridBox" to "react1": Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference`

Code

```
var data1 = {"Columns":[{"Title":"Title1","HTMLClass":"g1_Title"},{"Title":"Title2","HTMLClass":"g2_Title"},{"Title":"Title3","HTMLClass":"g3_Title"}],"Rows":[{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]}]};



var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Cell = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (column, i) {
                return (
                    <div className={column.HTMLClass}>{this.props.data.Cells[i]}</div>
                );
            })
        }
        return (
            <li>{Cell}</li>
        );
    }
});
var GridHead = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Cell = this.props.data.Title;
            var HtmlClass = this.props.data.HTMLClass;
        }
        return (
            <div className={HtmlClass}>{Cell}</div>
        );
    }
});
var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
                return (
                    <GridHead data={columns} />
                );
            });
            var Row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (data, i) {
                return (
                    <GridRow data={data1} key={i} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{Header}</li>
                {Row}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});


var GridBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <GridList data={data1} />
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only reference what is passed into the the function in map, unless you use bind, which maintains the instance of `this`, so that it is the same within the component and the function used within map.  This would allow you to use `this.props` within your mapping function.

Since `header` is using what is directly passed into the function in `map`, binding is not necessarily needed.  In `row`, in order to access `this.props`, the function must be bound.  For example if you had `somedata` you wanted to access within `this.props`:

```
var header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
    return (
        <GridHead data={columns} />
    );
});
var Row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (data, i) {
    return (
        <GridRow data={this.props.somedata} key={i} />
    );
}.bind(this));
```

note that in JSX regular variable names should start with a lowercase letter (as header above), whereas component names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup on the naming. But the binding? How does this work? Its not really the GridHead Im having problems with but the GridRow.

Comment: I expanded on the answer to address your comment.  Also note that when setting a key for row, it is a good idea to base it off of a data property that can serve as a unique identifier for that row.  This way if you add/remove/reorder rows, they wont have to re-render.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain more about the unique? Do you sugest that I manully add the id to the HTML element and on remove I do that also manually with javascript instead of forcing rerender? I thought that the virtuel dom with rerender was the whole point of reactJS?

Comment: It's not possible to demonstrate with the example data, but is important for applying this to real data.  Suppose that each row contained information for a person, and each person had a unique id number.  The unique id numbers could then be used as the keys, rather than the index of the loop.